# Code in node_modules is not reflected in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I have forked the vuejs-datepicker project on Github (because of a bug in the project, but that is irrelevant in this matter). The changes I make to this forked project does not reflect in the end result in the browser, in my project that are using this dependency.

Here´s what I do:

1. Add console.log´s, alerts and even remove som key functionality from the source code to make sure that the changes are easy to detect
2. Commit and push the changes to the forked project
3. In my main project I now run `npm update`, and afterwards I verify that the changes can be seen in the relevant file/files in the node_modules\vuejs-datepicker folder
4. I run `npm run serve` and my main project loads. The changes I´ve made is not reflecting in the browser

File in node_modules folder:
[image: File content in node_modules]

The compiled file in Chrome (I can verify that this is the running code with a breakpoint):
[image: compiled file in chrome]

Package.json:
[image: package.json]

I´ve tried clearing the npm cache with `npm cache clean`, removing the project reference from package.json and reference it again, bumping the version, but it seems like it is using some cache from the first time I used this forked project which I can´t seem to locate. I´ve also tried clearing the dist folder and my browser´s cache which had no effect, but I guess webpack is making sure this is not an issue.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: AFAIK `npm update` just updates packages. Have you compiled the Vue files?

Comment: Isn´t the requried/referenced dependencies from node_modules compiled, when i use npm build or npm run serve?

Comment: Are you editing the files for the date picker within the `node_modules` folder?

Comment: No, as stated in step 1. and 2. I change the vuejs-datepicker code in the source, push it to git, and then download/npm update it in my main project.

Comment: Since you're using Vue, you probably are using rollup or webpack with it. It may be configured to remove all `console.log`s from your code

Answer (score 5):

Try the following commands to reset `node_modules`

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but it´s been half a year and I´m not in the same situation anymore.

Comment: This ticket just had bounty placed on it by @wrkyle

Answer (score 0):

In case someone ended up here. Check other caches as well. In my case I use next.js and I have to delete `.next` folder